# Aplicar opacity em um Background

Tags: html, css, div, background, background-image

Estou tentando aplicar a opacidade pra minha imagem de background. Já tentei utilizar rgba, e a pseudo-classe after.
Existe alguma outra forma de aplicar esse filtro apenas na imagem, sem afetar o conteúdo?

Este é o HTML

```
<div id="banner" style="background-image: url(wp-content/themes/enepe/images/bg_header.jpg);">
```

E o CSS

```
#banner{
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: Use o opacity: 0.5; (Ou o que você preferir)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho sim, já utilizei mas ele aplica para tudo o que está na div...

Comment: Vê se ajuda: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas propriedades do CSS que quando aplicadas aos “elementos pais”, os “elementos filhos” herdam a característica aplicada no pai. **Esse estava sendo o seu caso**.  [Leia mais](https://tableless.com.br/efeito-cascata-e-especificidade-do-css/)

A propriedade CSS   [**opacity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)   especifica a transparência de um elemento, isto é, o grau no qual o background atrás do elemento é sobreposto

Usando `opacity: .4;`

```css
    .banner {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 5;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 400%;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .banner .bg {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIy6w.jpg) center center;
      opacity: .4;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        Eu Não estou opacitado? :)
    </div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, finalmente! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Usando RGBA, eu sempre utilizo dessa maneira :D

```css
.img{
    background: url('https://static.omelete.uol.com.br/media/extras/conteudos/01-Spoilers_fcaRwD9_4VjGalG.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.opac{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

.opac h1{
    color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
        <div class="opac">
            <h1>CONTEUDO</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
#banner {
   width: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
#banner:after{
   content : "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-image: url(wp-content/themes/enepe/images/bg_header.jpg); 
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity : 0.2;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta solução que o amigo postou está quase correta. Fiz algumas alterações de crossbrowser e incluí algumas propriedades necessárias. Deixei abaixo um live exemple. Espero ter ajudado.

** jsFiddle live preview

https://jsfiddle.net/gmtgr1ht/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=gmtgr1ht

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#banner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://www.jj.com.br/galerias/noticias/1000/codigo_0021653/2015-10-10_13-38-03_1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h3>See how the text is not transparent.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Desta forma ele não está conseguindo encontrar a imagem... Pra utilizar a imagem, eu utilizei um style direto na div...

Comment: Realmente era pra funcionar isso, já vi vários exemplos parecidos

Comment: @Patrick Oliveira tentou colocar o url absoluto da imagem? Talvez seja problema de encontrar o caminho relativo correto

Comment: @Patrick Oliveira você precisa substituir a url da imagem pela imagem que deseja carregar.